# How to show notification in IOS

Tags: ios, mysql, objective-c, notifications

I want to show notification after successful data insertion in MySQL. How to do this? for example. I added row with data to MySQL. Assume that the name and surname.I would want that after the addition of data to database automatic displaying pop ups (notification) in my app. Please help me . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Google push notifications for ios and Android

Comment: @BikashP this is not what he asks

Comment: Please post some code. Usually this is done with a completion handler

Comment: does u need server side code like in php to send the notification?

Answer (score 0):

You can Not directly show a notification when the app is in foreground.

To achieve what you are saying  you have to first generate a `LocalNotificaion` with a delay of 0.1Sec . And Check if your `application` is in `foreground` state then Make a `Custom View` and show it on `window`.

That's how you can do it.Let me know if their is any issue while doing this.